# Importing .sql file into MySQL using Java code

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to programmatically import a .sql file into MySQL.  The .sql file was generated by mysqldump.  I'm trying to do this dynamically in a Java program.  But, it keeps failing on the "<" character within Java (I think).  If I grab the String in the debugger of the command it's about to run (the "combined" variable below), and paste it into the command line, it works fine.  Likewise, when I was trying to get the mysqldump working inside this program, it failed on the ">" character, and I had to replace it with the "--result-file=" argument to get it to work.

```
    String command = mySqlPath + "mysql.exe";
    String user = "-u " + settings.dbUser;
    String password = "-p" + settings.dbPassword;
    String db = settings.dbDatabase;
    String inputFile = filePath + mySqlDumpFile;

    String combined = command + " " + user + " " + password + " " + db + " < " + inputFile;

    ExternalCommandExecuter ece = new ExternalCommandExecuter(combined);
    int code = ece.execute();
```

This results in this String for example

```
C:\software\mysql5\bin\mysql.exe -u root -p<password> 
db_name < C:\software\tomcat7\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\documents\dump-1461789460425.sql
```

Which will result in a exitCode of 1.  Pasting it into the command line, and it'll work.

Comment: But why goto all this trouble

Comment: Cause there will be dozens of dumps, and the software gives clients the ability to jump around to different points in time using the webapp.

Comment: No, the way I have it setup is better cause the sql dump files will be emailed around and used locally.

Comment: Can you share what is happening inside ExternalCommandExecuter.execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I couldn't get it to work in Java by importing the file with a "<", instead I had to write an external .sh/.bat file which I call from my Java code.