# How could I import an sql dump into all databases in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is there a way to execute an import on all present databases instead of specifying each like `mysql -uusername -ppw db_name < dump.sql`? In specific, I want to transfer all tables from one database to **every single other database**, so I dumped them, but since I have a ton of databases here, should I create a script or is there a workaround? I'd like to avoid making scripts as database names are encrypted so they resemble pseudorandom strings. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built-in like this, it's a fairly specific situation, and easily solved.  This can be a one-liner in shell/bash.  Retrieve your list of databases and feed them to a loop to load them.

- Set default user with:
- mysql_config_editor set -u username -p
- enter your password

One liner:

```
mysql -NBe "select schema_name from information_schema.schemata where schema_name not in ('mysql','performance_schema','sys','information_schema','others...')" | while read dbname ; do date; echo "loading $dbname"; mysql $dbname < dump.sql"; done
```

And block formatted for read-ability:

> mysql -NBe "select schema_name from information_schema.schemata
>   where schema_name not in ('mysql','performance_schema','sys',
>   'information_schema','others...')" | while read dbname ; do
>   date;
>   echo "loading $dbname";
>   mysql $dbname < dump.sql";
>   done

Depending on exactly how many "a ton" of databases is, and your available resources, split the list in 2, and run 2 concurrent sessions.

Comment: That's should be it! Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script in Java or php where you keep varying the db name and script will import the sql file in all db. You can take a look into below question -
[Importing .sql file into MySQL using Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36915555/importing-sql-file-into-mysql-using-java-code)